# babel-plugin-macros - MacroError: The macro you imported from "undefined" is being executed

Tags: typescript, babeljs, gatsby

I got a Gatsby website project. Since Gatsby's default babel config contains `babel-plugin-macros` I don't need much to set it up.

E.g. I've installed [preval.macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/preval.macro) and it works fine.

Now I want to create my own macro to do some stuff. So I created a new NPM package containing only the package.json, index.js and macro.js. The macro by itself does nothing by now.

But if I install the package and try to use it, I get

> MacroError: The macro you imported from "undefined" is being executed
>   outside the context of compilation with babel-plugin-macros. This
>   indicates that you don't have the babel plugin "babel-plugin-macros"
>   configured correctly.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.21-alpha",
  "description": "my package description",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "John Doe <john@doe.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
```

}

**index.js**

```
import macro from "./macro";
export default macro;
```

**macro.js**

```
import { createMacro } from "babel-plugin-macros";
export default createMacro(macro);
function macro({ references, babel, path }) {
    const { default: items = [] } = references;
    items.forEach((reference) => {
        if (!reference.parentPath.node.quasi) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

### Update

I would like to use the macro like this

```
import macro from "my-macro";

console.log(macro`something`)
```

### Update 2

I created codesandbox for a tiny gatsby starter project which shows the problem.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Knaackee/gatsby-babel-plugin-macros/tree/master)

Comment: Could you add a snippet of code showing how you're trying to use the macro? Including the babel config?

Comment: Thanks Kent! My question is updated. I dont have any babel config since gatsby already support babel-plugin-macros.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the import statement for the macro does not match the required convention for `babel-plugin-macros` to transform the code and call your custom macro.

You'll need to change the filename to end in `.macro` or import the macro file like: `my/macro`.

Learn more from the docs here: https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/master/other/docs/author.md#filename

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I've tried that with no success. I created codesandbox for a tiny gatsby starter project which shows the problem. I bet you will see the problem in no time. Thank You!!!!

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Knaackee/gatsby-babel-plugin-macros/tree/master

Comment: You need to make sure that the macro actually generates code that works. Remember that babel-plugin-macros will remove the import statement. Here I fixed the first macro as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bush-olpyw

It also doesn't appear to work on codesandbox. But it does work locally.